# NIntegrate/NSum with parameters

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I'm trying to calculate a continuous integral within a discrete integral.

Something similar to this (yet more complex):

```
NSum[NIntegrate[x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1}], {y, 2}]
```

I receive the following error code:

> NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand x^2+y has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. "

What is the proper way to tell Mathematica to evaluate this expression?

Comment: You can do `NSum[Integrate[x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1}], {y, 2}]`, but you can't use NIntegrate if there are symbolic terms in the integral inside. In any case, you should consider its form in your real problem

Comment: The actual function I am integrating over does not have an analytical integral that can be found. The integration has to be numeric in this case. No other solution?

Comment: [This is what you need](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820), even though `NSum` is `HoldAll`.

Comment: What if you interchange summation and integration?

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs - exactly what I was looking for.
(Changing order will cause the same issue).

Comment: The ["This is what you need"](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502) link has changed as [@Szabolcs noted here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/296824?sortMsg=Replies).